# React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CREATE_PROGRAM')

Tags: typescript, react-native, enums

I'd like to use an enum instead of magic string.

But for some reason React doesn't allow me that:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'CREATE_PROGRAM')`

Yet the code seems fairly simple:

`src/router/Router.tsx`

```
export enum Routes {
  HOME = 'Home',
  CREATE_PROGRAM = 'CreateProgram',
  ADD_EXERCISES = 'AddExercises',
  EDIT_WORKOUT = 'EditWorkout',
  EXERCISE_SETTINGS = 'ExerciseSettings',
  WORKOUT_PREVIEW = 'WorkoutPreview',
  SETS_RUNNER = 'SetsRunner',
  WORKOUT_SESSION_SUMMARY = 'WorkoutSessionSummary',
}
```

`src/home/repositories/home.fake-data.repository.ts`

```
import { Routes } from '../../router/Router'

export const dailyTasksFakeData: { description: string; route: Routes }[] = [
  {
    description: 'Create your first program',
    route: Routes.CREATE_PROGRAM,
  },
]
```

Comment: Hi Fix the import statement u r importing from other place point it to `src/home/HomeScreen.tsx`

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in the copy/pasting in this post, it's coming from the right file, I am editing my question